# how to find object in active record based month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

How to find object in active record based month?

example :

```
User.where("created_at = ?", "january")
```

I want collect all user created_at in january?
How can I do that?

I couldn't find any jQuery code to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this, but here's a good way that takes into account the servers time zone if it differs from UTC:

```
range = Time.new(2015, 1).beginning_of_month..Time.new(2015,1).end_of_month
User.where(created_at: range)
```

On PostgreSQL this results in a query similar to:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-01-01 08:00:00.000000' AND '2015-02-01 07:59:59.999999')
```

And on MySQL:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2015-01-01 08:00:00' AND '2015-02-01 07:59:59')
```